# Default Values in Fields not copying across in IBM Notes 9

Tags: lotus-notes, domino-designer-eclipse

I have created a form, and have put in all the fields the field name itself for the Default Value of the field. I have populated the field in a previous form. Then I go to the view select the document and create a new version of the form, but the values do not copy across can someone please help.

Thanks

Comment: Can you show some code please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the form properties. Enable "Form inherit values from selected document".
In the Field for the Default Value it is best practice to use `@ThisValue` to inherit the value.

[image]